# How to detect the last rows in selected state in UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

For maintaining rows selected and highlighted state when I run App again, I need to get the highlighted last selection in UITableView.

So, I choose the way to get titles of selected Rows and save these data in UserDefaults, and reload cellForRowAt with these.

I can make [String] of the titles that I selected by these codes.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    let selectedTitle = selectedCell?.textLabel!.text

    selectedTitleArray += [selectedTitle!]

    print(selectedCell?.textLabel!.text)
    print(selectedTitleArray)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let deselectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    let deselectedTitle = deselectedCell?.textLabel!.text
    selectedTitleArray = selectedTitleArray.filter{$0 != deselectedTitle}

    print(deselectedCell?.textLabel!.text)
    print(selectedTitleArray)
}
```

But when I put UserDefaults code in 'didSelectRowAt', it cannot detect 'didDeselectRowAt' after selection.

Of course, when I put UserDefaults code in 'didDeselectRowAt', it cannot detect 'didSelectRowAt' after deselection.

I don't know where I should put UserDefaults to save the last state of selection.

Where should I put UserDefault code?

Answer (score 0):

My misunderstand. UserDefaults works when I put it both.  
Let me explain step by step.

## 0. IndexPath vs. Titles

First, I recommend you to save not IndexPath of selected cells, but titles of selected cells.  
First, it is hard to save NSIndexPath in UserDefaults. UserDefaults cannot save NSIndexPath directly.  
Second, the order of data may change later. If you save IndexPath of selected cell, it is hard to deal with later.  
But, as long as a title is a constant, you can change whatever you want.

## 1. First step

First, globally, declare 'var selectedTitleArray: [String] = []' to get titles of selected rows and save in UserDefaults.
And, of course, globally, declare 'var passedTitleArray: [String] = []' to retrieve saved UserDefaults.

Here's the first code.

```
import UIKit

var selectedTitleArray: [String] = []
var passedTitleArray: [String] = []

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

## 2. Second step

Put 'selectedTitleArray' code to get titles of selected rows in 'didSelectRowAt' and 'didDeselectRowAt'.    
And, put 'UserDefalut.standard.set' code both 'didSelectRowAt' and 'didDeselectRowAt' to save titles of selected rows.

Here's the code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    let selectedTitle = selectedCell?.textLabel!.text

    selectedTitleArray += [selectedTitle!]

    print(selectedCell?.textLabel!.text)
    print(selectedTitleArray)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedTitleArray, forKey: "selectedTitle")
    print(passedTitleArray)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let deselectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    let deselectedTitle = deselectedCell?.textLabel!.text
    selectedTitleArray = selectedTitleArray.filter{$0 != deselectedTitle}

    print(deselectedCell?.textLabel!.text)
    print(selectedTitleArray)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedTitleArray, forKey: "selectedTitle")
    print(passedTitleArray)
}
```

## 3. Third step

Retrieve saved UserDefaults in 'viewDidLoad' code.

Here's the code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    passedTitleArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "selectedTitle") as! [String]
    print(passedTitleArray)
}
```

## 4. Fourth step

And, put checking string codes to reload cells in 'cellForRowAt' code.

Here's the code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    if passedTitleArray.contains(cell.textLabel!.text!) {
     print("Value exists!")
     tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
     } else {
     print("No value")
     }

    return cell  
}
```

## 5. Last step

**And, don't forget to initial value for UserDefault.**    
When you run this app first time, you will get 'Unexpectedly Nil' error message unless you set initial value for UserDefault.

Put 'UserDefault.standard.register' code in 'didFinishWithLaunchingWithOption' in 'AppDelegate.swift'

Here's the code.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["selectedTitle":[]])
    return true
}
```